# Assymptotic behaviors of European options

Tags: option-pricing, finance-mathematics, european-options

In some of the numerical works on Black-Scholes generalized models, the boundary conditions on the truncated domain taken from the asymptotic behaviors of European call options, which is given by
$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} u(\tau,x)=0,~\text{and}~\lim_{x \to \infty}u(\tau,x)-K(e^{x-\int_0^\tau D(s)ds}-e^{-\int_0^\tau r(s)ds}),$$
where, $u(\tau,x)$ is the option's value depending on the price variable $x$ and time variable $\tau$ with the strike price $K$. The parameters $r$ and $D$ represents the interest rate and dicividend yield repectively.

My doubt:

1. What precisely the financial importance of these asymptotic behaviors.
2. What type of hedging strategy is being processed at the truncated boundaries in numerical approaches.